# When is $\vec D$ or $\vec H$ constant throughout a change in medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, polarization, dielectric

My question is regarding what happens with $\vec D$ and $\vec H$, when the medium changes, in the case of $\vec D$ when the dielectric changes from $\epsilon_1$ to $\epsilon_0$ or to another $\epsilon_2$ and in the case of $\vec H$ when we change from a paramagnetic material with $\mu_1$ to $\mu_0$ or other $\mu_2$. I chose these 2 vectors because I believe they are built to help us to find the vectors $\vec B, \vec E$ and help us to get around different mediums easier.

Now let's just focus on $\vec H$ only (since I assume it is the same for $\vec D$ or similar), we have been taught the boundary conditions that are $$H^{||}_2-H^{||}_1=J_{free}$$ $$H^{\perp}_2-H^{\perp}_1=-(M^{\perp}_2-M^{\perp}_1)$$ with $||, \perp$ meaning parallel and perpendicular components, and 1 or 2 different mediums.

The thing is that I understand this, but teachers and solutions in book don't even seem to consider this when they want to find $\vec H, \vec B$ in all the regions.

---

*Example 1*. Solenoid of radius $a$ and length $L$ with a electric current $I$ running through it, the interior of the solenoid is partially filled uptil $b<a$ with a material of permeability $\mu$, find $\vec H, B$ in all regions.

The first thing they do is Ampere law to find $\vec H$ with $\oint \vec H\vec dl=I_{free}$ but they separate it from the cases where $r\leq a$ and from cases $r>a$, why? Without even applying anything of boundary conditions, they already know that those $H$ are different at $a$, but for example, not different at the boundary $b$ where the $\mu_0$ changes to $\mu$

---

*Example 2*. Between 2 cylindrical conductors of radius $R_1, R_2$, there is a potential applied $V_0$ and there exists 2 different materials with $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ like the picture shows, find $\vec E, \vec D$.

[image: Picture 1]

They now know without any boundary condition calculus that $\vec D$ is constant throughout $R_1\leq \rho \leq R_2$ and does not differ from the different dielectrics since thet just do $\oint D\vec dS=D2\pi\rho L=Q$, but now look at the last example

---

*Example 3*. Consider a spherical capacitor connected with $V_0$ such that there is a dielectric in half of the space between the spherical conductors like the figure shows, find $\vec E,\vec D$

[image: Picture 2]

They now apparently *do* separate the $D$ using the same Gauss law as before: $\\ D_0 2\pi r^2+D_d 2\pi r^2=Q$ being $D_0, D_d$ the auxiliary vector in no dielectric $\epsilon_0$ and in the dielectric of $\epsilon$, without using any boundary condition, they know it. And a problem which seems identical to the example 2 I gave, in this one they do make distinction of $D$ in different regions, but on example 2 they just don't, how?

---

**Conclusion**. How do I know where is $\vec D, \vec H$ constant, or I have to make a difference with cases in different places of the region? Of course it depends on the problem, but on what it depends so that I can know from where to go would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boundary conditions like $\vec E^{\parallel}_2=\vec E^{\parallel}_1$ and $\vec D^{\perp}_2=\vec D^{\perp}_1$ (across an interface with no free charge) occur frequently enough that they can sometimes be applied implicitly (perhaps for brevity). That doesn't mean the boundary conditions are not being applied.
2. Sometimes we can "guess" the solution (or its form), and then verify that it satisfies Maxwell's equations. The boundary conditions must also be checked, but the fact that they are obeyed might be obvious to the person doing the solution, so this check might be omitted.

In short, there is no secret to it. After solving problems like these for a while, you will develop the intuition to "automatically" apply the necessary boundary conditions without much mental effort. It is also a valid approach to guess the solution (assuming uniform $D$ in some region, etc.), check the boundary conditions, and revise your guess if needed.

---

**Example 1:** It is a well-known result (and is easily shown using Ampere's law) that the field outside an infinitely long solenoid is zero. More generally, $\vec H^{\parallel}$ has a discontinuity across the coil ($r = a$), since this interface carries free current. $\vec H^{\parallel}$ has no discontinuity across $r = b$ since there is no free current here. You see that we have applied the boundary conditions for $\vec H^{\parallel}$ without explicitly writing equations for it.

---

**Example 2:** I'm not sure what you mean by "$\vec D$ is constant", this is not true. $|\vec E|$ is uniform on a constant $\rho$ surface, not $|\vec D|$ ($\vec D$ is different in the two dielectrics). Obtain a solution with this assumption, then verify the boundary conditions at all interfaces (thus using method #2 mentioned above). As an exercise, you should also determine what boundary condition(s) are violated if you assume uniform $|\vec D|$ on a constant $\rho$ surface.

---

**Example 3:** $\vec D$ is different in the two dielectrics, just like in example 2. Again, you should verify that the solution you end up with obeys all the boundary conditions.

Comment: The thing is that in example 2, $\vec D$ is the same in different dielectrics, but in example 3 they are different since the solution shows $D_d$ and $D_0$ in the example 3, unlike in example 2 which only has one $D$

Comment: @Xetrez As I explained, $D$ will be different in the two dielectrics in example 2 (why?). The solution is wrong if it claims otherwise.

Comment: The solution in the second example says that there is only one $D$, that's why I'm confused

Comment: @Xetrez That is incorrect.